# Attach a license to each ExePackage in Wix Bundle

Tags: wix, licensing, package, bundle, burn

Is there a way to attach a license to each ExePackage in a Wix Standard Bundle Installer? For example, if I have a bundle that includes MSSQL Express, DotNet FrameWork 4.0 Full, and a MSI package. How do I attach MSSQL Express License to the MSSQL Express ExePackage and DotNet Framework license to Dotnet FrameWork ExePackage?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: in the .net installer you can make the installer not as a silent installer this way you would get the EULA agreement. if not i would try a bundle of bundles.

Comment: That's one option I didn't explored. Thank you very much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

with respect to user experience it would be recommended to have one License agreement containing all the Licenses so the user needs to accept one agreement i.e. a single installation experience.

Comment: Thank pb sanketh. That's what we concluded also.